# Do reactjs releases affect react native releases?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

With the release of `reactjs` 16, will the changes be also present in react native? Such as the `context` API and the new lifecycles? I am fairly new to `react-native` but have been coding in `reactjs` for `web` for some time now. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this question is yes since react native still inherits from `react` module. It just differs on where it is rendered ex. in web we use ReactDOM.